# Gradient show red color

Tags: android, gradient

Created new file in drawable and created this code to show gradient color.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:startColor="#FF795548"/>
</selector>
```

In the preview screen there is no preview, when I use as background 
`android:background="@drawable/drawableName"` I get red background.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the tag `selector` to the tag `shape`.
This is the new code after changing:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:startColor="#FF795548"/>
</selector>
```